# VBscript check for running process on multiple computers

Tags: vbscript

Below is a script I have been trying to put together to check if a process is running on a list of remote computers. It works, in that it reports that the process is running on the remote machine, but if it is not running, I get no indication and it just skips over that machine. All of my attempts to display an alternate message if the process is NOT running have failed. Is there a way to say if PROCESS.exe is not found, display:

"PROCESS NOT running on " & ComputerName

and then continue to loop through all of the machines?
Thanks for the help.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set listFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\list.txt")

Do While Not listFile.AtEndOfStream
ComputerName =  listFile.ReadLine()
Set Service = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & ComputerName &"")
    for each Process in Service.InstancesOf ("Win32_Process")
        If Process.Name = "PROCESS.exe" then
            wscript.echo "PROCESS running on " & ComputerName
        End If
    Next
Loop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set a flag in the inner loop when you find a matching process. That way you can print a message whether or not you found a process after the loop finishes. Also you should add some error handling (in case you can't connect to a server) and perhaps use `ExecQuery` with a filter for just the process name you're looking for, so that you don't have to retrieve all process names from all servers.

```
processname = "PROCESS.EXE"
query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='" & processname & "'"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\list.txt")

Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  skipServer = False
  server = f.ReadLine

  On Error Resume Next
  Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://" & server &"/root/cimv2")
  If Err Then
    WScript.Echo "Error " & Err.Number & " connecting to " & server ": " _
      & Err.Description
    On Error Goto 0
    skipServer = True
  End If
  On Error Goto 0

  If Not skipServer Then
    found = "not "
    For Each process in wmi.ExecQuery(query)
      found = ""
      Exit For
    Next

    WScript.Echo "PROCESS.EXE " & found & "running on " & server & "."
  End If
Loop

f.Close
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It really helped me understand what I should have gone for in the first place. The only issue was I had to flip the two "found" result text because they seemed to be reversed, but after a little tweak it was exactly was I was going for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not simply use a toggle?

```
   foundIt = false
   for each Process in Service.InstancesOf ("Win32_Process")
        If Process.Name = "PROCESS.exe" then
            foundIt = true
            exit for
        End If
    Next

    if (foundIt) then
       wscript.echo "PROCESS running on " & ComputerName
    else
       wscript.echo "PROCESS NOT running on " & ComputerName
    end if
```